# Check for newest Version of Program (Java)

Tags: java, server

I have a program in beta and I want to notice users when there is a new update avaible, so that they can have the best user experience. I thought about "asking" the server for the latest version and than look if its newer than the current one and notice him if his version is outdated. Any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: Too broad, you don't tell anything about how you want to get version, what is the server, etc there are tons of possible answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Java web start. From doc:

> Provides an easy, one-click activation of applications
>
> Guarantees that you are always running the latest version of the
>   application
>
> Eliminates complicated installation or upgrade procedures

See more https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info

Comment: It's certainly an option, but there is no "have to use". It's certainly possible to create a similar functionality yourself if needed, and I'd not be at all surprised if there are solutions to choose from if you search around a bit. JWS is really only suitable for applications with a graphical user interface.

Comment: I just want it to check the version not to run the application from the server. How would i do that?